# Use backbone routing without changing url

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have developed a webapp using backbone.js and more importantly a backbone router. Now I have been asked if this app that changes the URL depending on what section you visit, can be used within a single div as mini module on a website. Almost like a widget within a dashboard.

Any ideas how I could quickly implement this..... I feel like i'm missing a simple solution here.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Don't use the router?  Just call the same function to paint the screen that your router would call based on the url

Comment: simple solution. Boom! thanks @mainstreetmark